# Force CRLF on BeanIo Export

Tags: newline, bean-io

I want to force BeanIO to use CRLF as terminator when exporting a fixed-length stream. The following does not work

```
<stream name="marketFeed" format="fixedlength">
        <parser>
            <property name="recordTerminator" value="CRLF" />
        </parser>
```

I want to be tolerant for line-endings on parse, but want to use CRLF on export. This is in fact an I/O stream format.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<stream name="marketFeed" format="fixedlength">
    <parser>
        <property name="recordTerminator" value="\r\n" />
    </parser>
```

<strike>OR if it has to be escaped:</strike>

```
<stream name="marketFeed" format="fixedlength">
    <parser>
        <property name="recordTerminator" value="\\r\\n" />
    </parser>
```

CR usually implies \r and LF = \n. I haven't tested this though.

[OP comment]: no need to escape